Getting rasterized text in html canvas
I have main canvas on which I draw another canvas which had a text written on it. When I saw the results, it appears that the text is rasterized and not smooth.
Here is the code I tried :-


const mainCanvas = document.querySelector('.main');
const mainCanvasContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

const backgroundCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
backgroundCanvas.width = 1000
backgroundCanvas.height = 1000

const backgroundCanvasContext = backgroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

const run = async() => {
  const title = 'SQUARE'
  const text = title.toUpperCase();

  backgroundCanvasContext.font = '300px KulminoituvaRegular';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillText(text, 800/2, 30);
  mainCanvasContext.drawImage(backgroundCanvas, 0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);
};

run();
.main {
  
  background: blue;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'KulminoituvaRegular';
src: url('http://www.miketaylr.com/f/kulminoituva.ttf');
}
<canvas width="1000" height="1000" class="main"></canvas>



Problem: The final text canvas draw on the main canvas has blurry / rasterized text
Here is the Final Result :-


Please create a MRE of the problem using a code snippet for readers to run, and include the parts where the width and height of the canvas elements is set and where ctx comes from. Note canvas elements are a container for pixels, and will rasterize text pixels when text is written on them. When drawing the background canvas on the main canvas, the background pixels are interpolated as a rasterized image.

I made you a snippet. It does not show any text - possibly because you have ctx in the code but mainCanvasContext is the var and there is no text variable

Also we are missing the font. Do you have something like const font = new FontFace('MatterSQ', 'url(path/to/MatterSQ.woff2)'); ?

@mplungjan I tried a lot, but not sure why the text is not being rendered in top of the canvas here in the snippet?

Executing the snippet (at post revision 5) generates an error because ctx is undefined. You can see the error by running the snippet full screen and opening the browser console - I don't know why the error is not reported on the snippet console. Note if the main and background canvases are the same size there may not be any evidence of rasterization unless the font itself is a rasterized font - you might want to append backgroundCanvas to the body to see if it looks rasterized before drawing it on the main canvas.

Most certainly, you haven't synchronized the canvas dimensions in your original script - resulting in a blurry/pixellated rendering.
Keep in mind canvas.width (and height) won't return the final width as affected by CSS. If you haven't specified width and height as attributes for your <canvas> element or in your script canvas.width and canvas.height return the default: 300x150.
In the following example I retrieve the final dimensions via canvas.getBoundingClientRect().


const mainCanvas = document.querySelector('.main');
const mainCanvasContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');
console.log('original dimensions:', mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height)


const backgroundCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const backgroundCanvasContext = backgroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

// get dimensions of main canvas
let {
  width,
  height
} = mainCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
mainCanvas.width = width;
mainCanvas.height = height;
backgroundCanvas.width = width;
backgroundCanvas.height = height;

console.log('synchronized dimensions:', mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height)

const run = async() => {

  // load font
  const font = new FontFace("MatterSQ", "url('https://g.webfontfree.com/Code/WOFF/cc/c1/ccc1e1dc515b5e79736e3498cc9f0cf7.woff')", {
    style: "normal",
    weight: "400",
  });

  // wait for font to be loaded
  await font.load();
  // add font to document
  document.fonts.add(font);

  let text = 'SQUARE'
  backgroundCanvasContext.font = '100px MatterSQ';
  backgroundCanvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
  backgroundCanvasContext.textAlign = "center";
  backgroundCanvasContext.textBaseline = "middle";
  backgroundCanvasContext.fillText(text, width / 2, height / 2);

  //render to main canvas
  mainCanvasContext.drawImage(backgroundCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
};

run();
.main {
  width: 800px;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background: #ccc;
}
<canvas class="main"></canvas>



Besides, you need to wait for external fonts to bee fully loaded. You could use the fontFace API like so
  // load font
  const font = new FontFace("MatterSQ", "url('https://g.webfontfree.com/Code/WOFF/cc/c1/ccc1e1dc515b5e79736e3498cc9f0cf7.woff')", {
    style: "normal",
    weight: "400",
  });

  // wait for font to be loaded
  await font.load();
  // add font to document
  document.fonts.add(font);

